# Reactive couchbase issue content of this Observable (viewRow) is already released

Tags: java, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I’m using spring-data-couchbase with reactive approach & getting the following error:

> The content of this Observable (viewRow) is already released.
> Subscribe earlier or tune the CouchbaseEnvironment#autoreleaseAfter()

**Method definition**

```
default Flux<NonPrimitiveAsset> findAssetByParameters(StringBuilder whereClause) {

  WherePath selectFrom = N1qlUtils
      .createSelectFromForEntity(getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket().name());

  Statement statement = selectFrom.where(whereClause.toString());

  N1qlQuery query = N1qlQuery.simple(statement, N1qlParams.build());
  return ReactiveWrapperConverters
      .toWrapper(getCouchbaseOperations().findByN1QL(query, NonPrimitiveAsset.class), Flux.class);

}
```

**Caller method**

```
Flux<NonPrimitiveAsset> assetFlux = repository.findAssetByParameters(whereClause);

Mono<List<NonPrimitiveAsset>> assetsMono = assetFlux.collectList()
```

Comment: That error only occurs in SDC 3.x and earlier. Can you upgrade to Spring Data Couchbase 4.x?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. reindexing resolved the problem for me.
Try to add indexes or reindex for that query.